# How to find the dimensions of an array parameter in QBasic

Tags: arrays, function, qbasic

I have a QBasic function that takes two arrays as parameters.  I'd like to know if it's possible to find the number of dimensions those arrays have in the function.

For context, I'm writing an assertArrayEqual function for a QBasic unit testing library.

Comment: You might be able to do it by calling `LBOUND`/`UBOUND` and catching the error when the dimension is out of range, but QBasic's error handling is fairly ugly. I think you might be better off making separate functions for different dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to accomplish this.  As stated, you can determine the lower and upper bounds, but you must know beforehand how many dimensions the array contains.  To my knowledge this is not even available in higher level versions.

Comment: If you test the upper bounds of the array dimensions in a loop until an error occurs then you can count the dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done but it is not pretty: (QB64 source).

```
REM sample code to find number of dimensions in an array
DIM a(2, 2, 2) AS INTEGER
DIM SHARED E AS INTEGER
ON ERROR GOTO 10
CALL array(a())
END
10 E = -1: RESUME NEXT
SUB array (a() AS INTEGER)
DO
    X = X + 1
    T = UBOUND(a, X)
    IF E THEN
        X = X - 1
        PRINT "Array has"; X; "dimensions."
        EXIT DO
    END IF
LOOP
END SUB
```

Comment: The error which will occur is 9 (subscript out of range) and can be trapped.